# How to make a social media share button to share an iframe element vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to make a button to share a survey that's converted in iframe to mostly social media like facebook, twitter, whatsapp, telegram, email... But the components that I found are not working, so I want to know if its possible to create one or several buttons to share the survey. I'm using vue 2.0. The code of it goes like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12  pt-2 pl-md-1 mb-3 mb-lg-4">
      <div class="row ">
        <iframe
          id="livePlayerId"
          class="iframetv"
          src="....."
          width="100%"
          height="200px"
          frameborder="0"
          allow="autoplay; fullscreen"
        ></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div
      ref="survey"
      id="survey"
      class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 z-depth-1-half survey"
    >
      <iframe
        class="embed-responsive-item "
        scrolling="no"
        v-bind:src="
          'https://......' +
            surveyWidth +
            '/null/null/null/null/true'
        "
        allowfullscreen
      ></iframe>
    </div>

    <div v-show="loading">
      <b-skeleton animation="wave" v-for="index in 50" :key="index" />
    </div>

    <div v-show="!loading">
      <SideBarPost v-for="post in posts_1" :post="post" :key="post.id" />

      <SideBarPost v-for="post in posts_2" :post="post" :key="post.id" />
      <SideBarPost v-for="post in posts_3" :post="post" :key="post.id" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// <moreposts v-if="['home'].indexOf($route.name) > -1"></moreposts>
import ajax from "../mixins/ajax";
import SideBarPost from "../components/SideBarPost";

export default {
  name: "SideBar",

  mixins: [ajax],

  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      posts_1: [],
      posts_2: [],
      posts_3: [],
      surveyWidth: 250
    };
  },

  mounted: function() {
    this.getPosts();
    this.surveyWidth = this.$refs.survey.clientWidth;
  },

  computed: {},

  methods: {
    getPosts: async function() {
      let response1;
      let response2;
      let response3;

      try {
        response1 = await this.get(`/posts?per_page=6&categories=56`);
        response2 = await this.get(`/posts?per_page=6&categories=5721`);
        response3 = await this.get(`/posts?per_page=6&categories=65`);
      } catch (error) {
        this.loading = false;
        return;
      }

      this.posts_1 = await this.getFeaturedImages(response1.data);
      this.posts_2 = await this.getFeaturedImages(response2.data);
      this.posts_3 = await this.getFeaturedImages(response3.data);

      this.loading = false;
    },

    getFeaturedImages: function(posts) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        let requests = posts.map(post => {
          return new Promise(async resolve => {
            let response;

            try {
              if (post.featured_media <= 0) {
                throw "No featured image.";
              }

              response = await this.get(`/media/${post.featured_media}`);
              post.featured_image =
                response.data.media_details.sizes["medium"].source_url;
            } catch (error) {
              post.featured_image = null;
            }

            resolve(post);
          });
        });

        Promise.all(requests).then(posts => resolve(posts));
      });
    }
  },

  components: {
    SideBarPost
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.survey {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 320px;
  margin-bottom: 250px;
}

// iframe {
//   height: 9.5rem;
//   width: 100%;
// }
.iframetv {
  height: 9.5rem;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Why not share the link to the survey directly?

Comment: Because it's generated via survey builder and it doesn't have the functionality to integrate sharing buttons.